# Is it possible to create a symbolic link on Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to know if in android it is possible to create symbolic links from my android application, because I want to create a symbolic link of the folder / data of my application with / sdcard. I am not an expert on android, but I usually do it in java using the Java.nio.File.Files class but in android this class is not allowed, I know that in android there is a way that is by using api 21 with The Os.symlink () method, but this is for android 5.0 and I need it for the minimum android 4.0 or 4.1 onwards. If you know any way please let me know, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as a command with the Process class.

```
Process symlink = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink");
```

Comment: Do not create me in the file link, use your code like this: `try {
     Process symlink = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /sdcard/Enlace.txt /sdcard/Mob/Enlace.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Comment: Do not create me in the file link? The hell does that mean?

Comment: Forgive my syntax, what I wanted to say was: is that the link file was not created in the desired directory (it just was not created). Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `Os.symlink(originalFilePath, symLinkFilePath)` (link [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#symlink(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))), starting from Lollipop.

If you want to support from older Android versions, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107194/878126).